# Como editar um item existente do localStorage em uma url blob

Tags: javascript

Como editar um item existente no localStorage em uma página HTML em blob?

O item vem de outra página e é substituído na página de blob, mas quando você tenta substituí-lo, acaba criando um novo acessível apenas dentro da página blob, não é possivel acessa-lo fora da pagina em blob, nem mesmo pelo console do navegador, procurei sobre isso e não achei nada informando essa limitação do blob.

**É possível editar o item fora da pagina em blob com o mesmo dominio?**

Link de um exemplo no codepen: https://codepen.io/markvaaz/pen/LYYZgYE

```js
//cria um item no localStorage (Ainda em um pagina comum)
localStorage.setItem("test", "not working")
//cria uma url blob
function newBlob(text){
  var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", text], {type: "text/html"})
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  return url
}
//da um conteúdo para o blob e entra na url blob retornada
window.location.href = newBlob(`<button onclick="localStorage.setItem('test', 'working')">Click here to replace the item</button>`)
//a função do botão é substituir o item que foi criado anteriormente com um novo conteúdo, porém acaba criando um novo item acessivel apenas dentro da pagina blob, não é possivel acessar o item no console do navegador.
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando seu script começa a ser interpretado ele salva um valor no `localStorage`, constrói a função `newBlob` e troca o `href` passando o resultado da função `newBlob`.

Ao substituir o `href` é como se você trocasse de endereço, então supondo que seu endereço local (um arquivo local `.html`) seja `C:/meudiretorio/arquivo.xml` ao substituir o `href` passando o Object URL, seu navegador irá trocar o endereço para por exemplo `blob:null/9feeeee0-bba8-4f70-b63f-4b3d015a5996`.

Trocando a origem do documento o `localStorage` será diferente e por esta razão não funcionará. Então considerando sua pergunta, nestas condições, a resposta será: não é possível.

Comment: mesmo que o blob esteja no mesmo domínio de uma pagina normal? como por exemplo no codepen o dominio `https://cdpn.io/...` em seguida `blob:https://cdpn.io/cd18b45a-84ea-4a2b-9cad-3bb488d0f28f`

Comment: @MarkVaaz no codepen a origem do documento não muda. Toda vez que você altera o código ele troca apenas o final do `src` do iframe: `https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/index.html?key=iFrameKey-XXXXX` o endereço origem do documento permanece inalterado. Neste caso, como a origem é a mesma, o `localStorage` funciona utilizando sua lógica. Toda vez que a origem for alterada o `localStorage` terá uma nova instância associada a origem.

Comment: No caso, não funciona no codepen, e na verdade o src do iframe não muda, mas conforme você passa um novo endereço ele passa a ser o novo endereço do iframe.

Comment: @MarkVaaz acabei de abrir seu link no codepen e está funcionando corretamente. Ao clicar no botão o valor `working inside the blob` é exibido no `body.innerHTML`. Se você retirar o trecho `localStorage.setItem('test', 'working inside the blob ');` será exibido "not working". Veja que o localStorage é o mesmo antes e depois do clique já que a origem do documento não foi alterada. Se você puder, detalhe um pouco mais por favor sua dúvida caso não tenha ficado claro

Comment: @MarkVaaz apenas complementando, a origem do `src` do iframe se mantém. Englobe seu script com um setTimeout de uns 2s e logo na primeira linha fora do setTimeout printe o endereço. Você verá algo do tipo: https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/index.html?key=iFrameKey-edca7c65-9f25-598b-56cf-f3ea718d9a4e e depois de 2s blob:https://cdpn.io/c42af343-2b6b-4679-996e-78c71a97c2d3