# Como criar paginas temporarias no lado do cliente?

Tags: javascript

Um tempo atrás estava procurando soluções para criar paginas temporárias pelo lado do cliente, hoje encontrei algo parecido nessa postagem: [Como editar um item existente do localStorage em uma url blob](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416437/como-editar-um-item-existente-do-localstorage-em-uma-url-blob)

Porém como pude ver há uma limitação para retirar informações da pagina em blob, por que aparentemente o localStorage é restrito a pagina blob, testei os cookies e também são.

Teria alguma outra maneira de criar paginas temporárias pelo lado do cliente sem a necessidade de um servidor?

```js
function newBlob(text){
  var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", text], {type: "text/html"})
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  return url
}
newBlob('HTML AQUI')
//retorna a url em BLOB
```

Comment: Usando as API's `ServiceWorker`, `Cache` e `Response` vc pode criar páginas apenas no lado do cliente, inclusive adicionando recursos exclusivos para estas paginas (CSS, JavaScript, imagens, etc). A parte "trabalhosa" é montar toda esta estruturação de páginas no lado do cliente e refazer isto (ou nao) sempre que atualizar o cache.

Comment: Com o `ServiceWorker` eu conseguiria extrair informações da pagina temporária via `localStorage` e acessar em uma pagina comum?

Comment: Com `ServiceWorker` uma página criada no frontend seria tratada como uma pagina "comum"... com todos os recursos a disposição. O que for armazenado na página "criada" (`IndexedDB`, `localStorage`, `cookie`) pode ser "recuperado" em outras páginas no mesmo domínio.